# How to set Mask property of RadMaskedTextBox( in EditItemTemplate) dynamically on Selected index changed event of RadComboBox in Radgrid

Tags: telerik, masking, itemtemplate, selectedindexchanged

How to set the `Mask` property of `RadMaskedTexbox`, which is in `EditItemTemplate` in one column of `Radgrid`, on `SelectedIndexChanged` Event of `RadCombobox`, in `EditItemTemplate` of another column, in `Radgrid`, which is in Batch Edit Mode?

**Note:** `RadGrid` is in `BatchEdit` Cell Mode.

Not able to find the `RadMaskedTextbox` control, on selected index changed event of `Combobox`.

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ID="rdcbxCountry" SelectedValue='<%# Eval("Country") %>' runat="server" RenderMode="Auto" AutoPostBack="True" EnableLoadOnDemand="true" OnItemsRequested="rdcbxCountry_ItemsRequested" OnSelectedIndexChanged="rdcbxCountry_SelectedIndexChanged"></telerik:RadComboBox>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                        </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>

                        <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Office Phone" SortExpression="Office_Phone" UniqueName="Office_Phone" HeaderStyle-Width="120px">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblOfficePhone" runat="server" Text=' <%# Eval("Office_Phone") %>' Width="110px">
                                </asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                 <telerik:RadMaskedTextBox RenderMode="Lightweight" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Office_Phone") %>' Mask="(###) ###-####" Width="`enter code here`110px"
                                    ID="txtOfficePhone">
                                </telerik:RadMaskedTextBox>
                            </EditItemTemplate>

                        </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this was posted a while back...

I was able to capture the grid_ItemDataBound event, and call a 'change' method in there. Like you, I also have a 'click-event' to the control I wanted to capture. Something like:

```
Private Sub grd_ItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As Telerik.Web.UI.GridItemEventArgs) Handles grd.ItemDataBound

If e.Item.OwnerTableView.Name = "Grid" Then
  rdcbxCountry_SelectedIndexChanged(e.Item.FindControl("rdcbxCountry"), New System.EventArgs)
EndIf

End Sub

Protected Sub rdcbxCountry_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

   Dim rdcbxCountry As RadComboBox= CType(sender, RadComboBox)
   Dim txtOfficePhone= CType(rdcbxCountry.Parent.FindControl("txtOfficePhone"), RadMaskedTextBox)

   If rdcbxCountry.SelectedValue = "US" then
      txtOfficePhone.Mask = "(###) ###-####"
   Else
      ...
   End If

End if
```

Good luck!